# How can I pull back only records where column has matching data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to pull back data from a table where a column has matching items. This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
SELECT 
    @@SERVERNAME AS Instance, 
    DB_NAME() AS [DataBase],
    co, id,
    changedBy,
    oldValue, newValue
FROM 
    Table1 T1
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, changeDate) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
    AND column1 = 'name1'
    AND column2 IN ('name2','name3')
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 T2 WHERE T1.newValue = T2.newValue )>3
```

This is a table made up of changes that happen from triggers. I need to be able to query this table and pull back any items that match in the criteria.

Here would be an example of the table

```
instance | database | co  | id | changedby | oldvalue | newvalue
----------------------------------------------------------------
sql01    |  123     | abc | 01 |  user1    |   1234   |    5678
```

There could be millions of these type of records daily. What I need to pull back are only rows where newvalue is the same on 4 or more rows. Since this database is full of personal information (I work for a company that deals with banking) I'm looking for rows where bank routing and accounting may have been fraudulently changed.

Comment: can you show a table of the results you are getting, and also mock a table of your desired results?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results so we know what you are asking about.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on "Doesn't seem to be working". Looks fine to me. I'd be happy to execute this fine query if I were a DB.

Comment: Also, just to clarify. That last condition in your WHERE statement is going to only return records from your table where `newvalue` shows up 4 or more times in the table. In case that's a point of confusion, which is reasonable, because it could be confusing, which is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregate window function:

```
;with cte as(select *, count() over(partition by newvalue) as rn
             from table1 
             where ...)
select * 
from cte
where rn > 3
```

Note: you should remove this from `where` clause:

```
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 T2 WHERE T1.newValue = T2.newValue )>3
```